# Self-referential association in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, self-reference

I have model called test, and test can have many tests, and should be able to have a reference to it's parent test if it exists. EG

- test <-- parent doesn't exist

  - test

    - test
    - test

      - test
    - test
  - test
- test <-- parent doesn't exist

i've seen a couple of possible solutions with examples before 2.3, but how models handle references seems to have changed a lot since 2.0. I was wondering if anyone has a best route option for doing this with some 2.3 spiffiness. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If each test can have one parent and many children, this seems like an ideal use for [`acts_as_tree`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Acts/Tree/ClassMethods.html) or [`acts_as_nested_set`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Acts/NestedSet/ClassMethods.html).